# MySQL: BTREE Slow Index Path (Table Size: 723704015 Rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a large database, and one table in particular is consistently slow, despite having an appropriate index (fk, actually) on the column.  To be fair, the column has low cardinality (only 5 possible values, and are not distributed equally), but doing a `LIMIT 1` is still 9+ seconds, but *only* when selecting on a particular path of the btree.

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `locking_scripts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `script_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `transaction_output_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `script` blob NOT NULL,
  `address_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `locking_scripts_uq` (`transaction_output_id`),
  KEY `locking_scripts_address_id_fk` (`address_id`),
  KEY `locking_scripts_type_id_fk` (`script_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `locking_scripts_address_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `addresses` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `locking_scripts_output_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_output_id`) REFERENCES `transaction_outputs` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `locking_scripts_type_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`script_type_id`) REFERENCES `script_types` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=748705501 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The column in question is `script_type_id`.  The contents of this corresponding table are:

```
+----+------------------------+
| id | type                   |
+----+------------------------+
|  2 | CUSTOM_SCRIPT          |
|  3 | PAY_TO_PUBLIC_KEY      |
|  4 | PAY_TO_PUBLIC_KEY_HASH |
|  5 | PAY_TO_SCRIPT_HASH     |
|  1 | UNKNOWN                |
+----+------------------------+
```

A `table status` for the two tables is:

```
+-------------------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name              | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows      | Avg_row_length | Data_length  | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-------------------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| locking_scripts   | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 726718877 |             70 |  51335135232 |               0 |  34351300608 |   7340032 |      748705501 | 2018-10-25 01:31:20 | 2018-11-18 15:30:40 | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| script_types      | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |         5 |           3276 |        16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              6 | 2018-10-24 22:22:43 | NULL                | NULL       | utf8mb4_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-------------------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

The query I'm running is:

```
SELECT id FROM locking_scripts WHERE script_type_id = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

...which takes about `9.5s` to execute.  The profile of this query is:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys              | key                        | key_len | ref   | rows      | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | locking_scripts | ref  | locking_scripts_type_id_fk | locking_scripts_type_id_fk | 4       | const | 363359438 |   100.00 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

The profiler says it's using the index (to be fair, it has to filter 363,359,438 rows, but with the `LIMIT 1` it should quite fast since it bails out on the first match).  However, the interesting thing is this query is twice as fast:

```
SELECT id FROM locking_scripts WHERE script_type_id NOT IN (2, 3, 4, 5) LIMIT 1
```

...Which takes `4.5s` to execute.  (Though this is still a terribly long time.)  I have other tables similarly sized, and selecting a `LIMIT 1` from a similarly indexed set is near-instant.

For completeness, the explain on the "faster" version is as follows:

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys              | key                        | key_len | ref  | rows      | filtered | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | locking_scripts | range | locking_scripts_type_id_fk | locking_scripts_type_id_fk | 4       | NULL | 363359442 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+
```

I'm running out of ideas to explain why I'm seeing this kind of result.  If anyone has any insight, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

---

**Additional Information, per comments:**

Execution Plan for `SELECT *`:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM locking_scripts WHERE script_type_id = 1 LIMIT 1;

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "locking_scripts",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": ["locking_scripts_type_id_fk"],
      "key": "locking_scripts_type_id_fk",
      "key_length": "4",
      "used_key_parts": ["script_type_id"],
      "ref": ["const"],
      "rows": 363359438,
      "filtered": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Execution Plan for `SELECT * ... NOT IN ()`:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM locking_scripts WHERE script_type_id NOT IN (2, 3, 4, 5) LIMIT 1;

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "locking_scripts",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": ["locking_scripts_type_id_fk"],
      "key": "locking_scripts_type_id_fk",
      "key_length": "4",
      "used_key_parts": ["script_type_id"],
      "rows": 363359442,
      "filtered": 100,
      "index_condition": "locking_scripts.script_type_id not in (2,3,4,5)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check something else...  Get the `EXPLAINs` for both queries when you do `SELECT * ...` instead of `SELECT id ...`.  It should stop saying "Using index", but I wonder if something else will change.  Also, please get `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT id ...` for both cases.

Comment: @RickJames I ran them with a `SELECT *`--both have very similar performance results.  I'll add the results to the question.

Answer (score 0):

(Too big for a Comment.)

So far, I am stumped.  The JSONs are different, but they don't tell me enough.  Here's another thing to experiment with:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

This is a general technique for getting the actual counts of certain actions.  It may help decide whether the "1" row came early or later in the scan.